# Are there any plans for releasing new Interface for LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

With all my respects, LibreOffice seems to be a very old version of Microsoft Office.

LiberOffice Team should work on it GUI (Icons, Appearance), so is there any plans to improve its appearance?

Is there any enhancement I can download?

I like to see LiberOffice charming and competing Microsoft Office.

Comment: That is up to their developers to do, we don't have such expertise.

Comment: You mean like a theme?

Answer (score 6):

Here's my interface :

[image: sifr]

This is the *Sifr theme* for LibreOffice 4.2

If you have LibreOffice 4.2, you can install the *Sifr theme* with :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-sifr
```

---

If you don't have Libreoffice 4.2, install it with :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

A few other themes are available, install them with :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style*
```

---

You can also use Google to find themes for LibreOffice (any version), and apply them yourself.

Themes for LibreOffice are `.zip` files and go into `/usr/share/libreoffice/share/config/` directory.

Comment: And if you don;t have Libreoffice 4.2 - run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`, `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` - from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/upgrade-to-libreoffice-42-in-ubuntu.html).

Comment: Oh, and `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style*` seems to install a few other interesting themes - KDE theme etc.

Comment: LinuxMint has a style called 'Breeze' as well, you should be able to find it [here](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/import/libr/libreoffice/). I think the Human theme works best out of the available bunch though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also [use Firefox themes in Libreoffice](http://andybrandt531.com/2013/02/customize-new-libreoffice-4point0/).

Find a theme you like [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/). Note down the URL of the theme you like - here is a bad example:

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ubuntu-theme-for-libreoffic/
```

In Libreoffice 4.2 *(Firefox themes I think are supported from version 4 onwards)*, Go to *'Tools'* > *'Options'*, then go the the *'Personalisation'*.
 Click *'Own theme'*, and enter the URL of the theme you liked. Wait for it to download, and:
[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Libreoffice Theme]

Answer (score 2):

LibreOffice have made significant changes to the user interface recently but why ask them to mimic Microsoft Office?  (Warning: Opinion) I am a heavy user of word processors for producing long and quite complex documents such as tender and contract documents for large projects.  I found the Ribbon Interface introduced by Microsoft in about 2007 far less efficient than the "old" interface.  For example keyboard short cuts were no longer "advertised" in menu options.  It was part of the reason for a complete change to, then, OpenOffice and subsequently LibreOffice.

Comment: I have both Microsoft Office  2007 and  LibreOffice. The ribbon doesn't bother me. What bothers me is that LibreOffice has more features that I need than Microsoft Office 2007, which makes my work much faster in LibreOffice. LibreOffice interface for me is much faster than MS Office, and I have had buggy performance before in MS Office, but never in LibreOffice.

Comment: @karel - but with MS Office you can save large important documents with a 50/50 chance of it crashing, corrupting the file :)

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice recently released a beta 5.3 that contains a ribbon interface.  The full article by omgubuntu are located [Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/microsoft-office-ribbon-ui-coming-libreoffice)

You can download it direct from libreoffice [Here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=rpm-x86_64&version=5.3.0&lang=en-US)
I had trouble downloading it and was successful with the torrent.

unzip the file into its own directory (right click and say "extract here")  then go into that directory via terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Once you are installed open it up by typing "writer"  you will now see two programs.. the new one is called writerdev.

Go to advanced options and choose "experimental features"
Go to view/toobars and choose notebookbar
Go to view/notbookbar and choose 3 options as you like.
If you lose your menu, you can turn it on or off by the leftmost icon "menubar" will toggle it on or off.

[image: screen shot]